# Direcinomento de páginas com codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, view

Olá! Vou ser bem breve.
Estou tendo problemas para definir uma href="" correta. Apos clicar em um link no menu, ele está direcionando para página do HOSTGATOR '404 - página não encontrada'
aqui vai o código do controller:

```
class Posts extends CI_Controller {

    //Página de listar posts
public function index()
{
        // Carrega o model posts
        $this->load->model('posts_model', 'posts');

        // Criamos a array dados para armazenar os posts 
        // Executamos a função do posts_model getPosts
        $data['posts'] = $this->posts->getPosts();

        // Carregamos a view listarprodutos e passamos como parametros a array posts que guarda todos os posts
        // da db posts
    $this->load->view('listarposts', $data);
}

// Página de listar reiki
public function reiki()
{

        // Carrega a model posts
        $this->load->model('posts_model', 'posts');

        // Carrega a view
        $this->load->view('listarreiki');
}
```

}

Aqui vai a view com o href com o link:

```
  <ul class="list-unstyled">
                <li><a href="posts/reiki">Reiki</a></li>        
      </ul><span class="heading">Email</span>
```

To aprendendo agora o codeigniter e to utilizando para um site que estou desenvolvendo.
Teria que modificar em routes.php ou em autoload.php?
Alguém poderia me ajudar.

Comment: Não precisa adicionar a rota. Como a url é `post/reiki` e a classe é `post`, método `reiki`, o CI irá reconhecer. Qualquer coisa você pode adicionar `/posts/reiki`. Talvez você esteja entrando em uma URL que realmente não existe. Você também pode verificar o `.htaccess` (caso seu servidor seja apache) https://gist.github.com/philipptempel/4226750

Comment: Vc pode ativar o helper url e usar `base_url('posts/reiki')`. Também pode ser que a [remoção do index.php](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/urls.html?highlight=index%20php#removing-the-index-php-file) resolva o caso.

Comment: fiz todas as mudanças que comentaram, mas nada adiantou. Continua direcionando para página não encontrada.

Answer (score 0):

Para retirar a necessidade de colocar sempre o index.php nas urls você precisa criar um arquivo .htaccess na raiz do seu projeto com o seguinte código:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

É aconselhável também colocar o caminho completo nas urls. Para fazer isso o codeigniter disponibiliza um helper chamado **url** para auxiliar nesse processo. 
Para usar esse helper vá no arquivo autoload.php que fica na pasta application/config/ e adicione o halper

```
$autoload['helper'] = array('url');
```

Agora no arquivo config.php que fica na pasta application/config/ você coloca sua url base. Vai ficar algo como:

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/meuprojeto/';
```

Agora toda vez que você precisar usar a url do seu site basta chamar o métido **base_url('posts/reiki/')**. No seu exemplo o href ficaria algo do tipo:

```
href="<?php echo base_url('posts/reiki/')?>"
```

Comment: No caso, meu projeto ta em um servidor web, seria necessário subir o arquivo .htaccess ou o servidor já possui as configurações necessárias? Em autoload.php e config.php vou fazer as alterações e já retorno.

Comment: você tem que subir o arquivo. Em geral os servidores aceitam por padrão arquivos .htaccess. O código que coloquei é o mínimo que tem que ter para funcionar. A função dele é redirecionar qualquer solicitação para seu site para o arquivo index.php

Comment: Eu tento subir o arquivo  .htaccess mas não aparece. o que será?

Comment: Não aparece no upando, nem na raiz do meu projeto

Comment: arquivos que comecem por . são arquivos ocultos. Veja se seu servidor está configurado para vc visualizar arquivos ocultos

Comment: Olá! Consegui resolver, o arquivo .htaccess estava oculto então habilitei para visualizar nas configuração. Após as mudanças que você indicou resolveu o meu problema. Obrigado!